# PHP HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request from API Request with authorization headers

Tags: php, authentication, https

I am trying to retrieve some data from an API that requires authentication via HTTPS. I have the correct authentication, however when using 'file_get_contents' to get the data I am getting the error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

```
$api_url = 'https://api...';

$client_id = 'user';
$client_secret = 'pass';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret"),
    ),
));

$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
```

Would there be any particular reason why I am unable to get the data from the authenticated server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the authentication in the right way.
The php code is correct.

I think that the problem is the url of request.
Because the response return an 400 code, this mean that the authentication works but the request url to API is wrong.

Code 400: Bad request, for example some wrong or missing params in request.

Code 401: unauthorized. (Not you case)

With this infos we can not help you at all.
Check url params, read api docs if you can or post more infos about url, or api :)

Byee

Edit Solution:

Check if url has some special char or spaces. Maybe you only need to encode url.

WARNING: Do not encode all url, but only the parameter values.

Example:

```
 http ://example.com/test?file=This is a file.txt
```

to:

```
 http ://example.com/test?file=This%20is%20a%20file.txt
```

Comment: If I manually copy the url onto my browser and add the authentication parameters I get the data. The request url is correct

Comment: Ok, are you sure that the auth is basic?

Comment: Yes, the auth is basic

Comment: Ok, another thing that you can check is the url. Check if it has some special char or spaces. Maybe you only need to encode url.

Comment: You need to encode only the parameters part. Not all url, for example: http ://example.com/test/file?=[this is a file.txt] <- encode part inside brackets

Comment: I had spaces in the url that should have been %20 (the space character) instead

Comment: Exactly. You only need to change space char with '%20' that is the encoded value of space char

Answer (score 1):

Http error 400 means "Bad Request".

The remote server is not happy with your request. Maybe you are not building your $context variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your `header` key should be an array containing the headers for the request:

```
$api_url = 'https://api...';

$client_id = 'user';
$client_secret = 'pass';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$client_id:$client_secret"))
                 // ^ check here
    ),
));

$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);
```

Comment: No, doesn't change anything